# Mat-tree more text border align issue

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, angular-material

mat-tree more text border line missing how to fix [this https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-nested-c6ydkc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-nested-c6ydkc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to fix the button alignment problem!

```
.alignment-fix {
  .mat-tree-node {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: end !important;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-nested-pshefx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,styles.scss)